# From list of lists to list of lists of lists

Tags: python, list, folium

i have a list like this:

```
first_list = [[ 1.        , 45.4,  9.1],
              [ 2.        , 45.5,  9.1],
              [ 2.        , 45.4,  9.2],
              [ 2.        , 45.4,  9.2],
              [ 3.        , 45.4,  9.1],
              [ 3.        , 45.4,  9.1],
              [ 3.        , 45.4,  9.1] ]
```

I want to use the folio function `HeatMapWithTime`, and to do that i need to group the data above according to the first item of each sublist (1., 2., 3. ecc):

```
new_list = [ [ [45.4, 9.1] ],                               # All coords for 1.
             [ [45.5, 9.1], [45.4, 9.2], [45.4, 9.2] ],     # All coords for 2.
             [ [45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.2] ] ]    # All coords for 3.
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution using `pandas`, a wise choice when dealing with complex data formats:

```
import pandas as pd    
pd.DataFrame(first_list).set_index(0).groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist()).tolist()
#-> 
[[[45.4, 9.1]],
 [[45.5, 9.1], [45.4, 9.2], [45.4, 9.2]],
 [[45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.1]]]
```

Comment: Great, i'm using pandas, so i came back to the original df and ran this command: ```heat_list = df.groupby(df.day).apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist()).tolist()```. The output return a sub-sublist like this: ```[1.0, 45.44430542, 9.16762733]```, but i don't want the first element, only lat and lon. How can i do that?

Comment: @Ibarrond pandas can be really useful, but I think this solution is very complex (difficult to debug in the future) and I suspect it could be quite slow

Comment: I agree, but I use Pandas very often, that's why i'd like to solve the problem in this way.

Comment: @Nathan if you execute each operation step by step, you can debug it incredibly easy. WRT performance, unless the question asks for it, there is no point on providing an ultrafast solution, but rather one that can be understood and reused.

Comment: @alcor I would try something like this: `heat_list = df.groupby(df.day).apply(lambda x: x.values[1:].tolist()).tolist()`. (Note the [1:] to remove the first element)

Comment: @ibarrond I've been programming in python for several years now and it took me a second to understand what your function does. Having had to work on legacy code containing many examples of such solutions I politely dissagree about how easy it is to find (and solve) such errors

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the list is sorted by the first elements, as it seems, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
[[i[1:] for i in v] for k,v in groupby(first_list, itemgetter(0))]

#[[[45.4, 9.1]],
# [[45.5, 9.1], [45.4, 9.2], [45.4, 9.2]],
# [[45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.1]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can collect all coordinates in a dictionary:

```
res = {}
for entry in first_list:
    res.setdefault(entry[0], []).append(entry[1:])
```

This gives you:

```
>>> res
{1.0: [[45.4, 9.1]],
 2.0: [[45.5, 9.1], [45.4, 9.2], [45.4, 9.2]],
 3.0: [[45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.1]]}
```

If your list was already sorted, convert the values into a list (Python 3.6+ only):

```
>>> list(res.values())
[[[45.4, 9.1]],
 [[45.5, 9.1], [45.4, 9.2], [45.4, 9.2]],
 [[45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.1]]]
```

Otherwise, you need to sort them first:

```
>>> [res[key] for key in sorted(res.keys())]
[[[45.4, 9.1]],
 [[45.5, 9.1], [45.4, 9.2], [45.4, 9.2]],
 [[45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.1]]]
```

Comment: 'If your list was already sorted, convert he values into a list' Are you sure about that? I thought dictionaries don't preserve order

Comment: Starting from Python 3.6 the do preserve insertion order. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to first sort your list:

```
lst_data = sorted(first_list)
```

And then to loop over it, creating a new ljst when the fist index changes:

```
first_index = None
final_lst = []
for i in lst_data:
    if i[0] != first_index:
        final_lst.append([])
        first_index = i[0]
    final_lst[-1].append(i[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dict for that, you might want to bring it back to a list, if you need it as a list, but using a dict for grouping is usually helpful:

```
first_list = [[ 1.        , 45.4,  9.1],
              [ 2.        , 45.5,  9.1],
              [ 2.        , 45.4,  9.2],
              [ 2.        , 45.4,  9.2],
              [ 3.        , 45.4,  9.1],
              [ 3.        , 45.4,  9.1],
              [ 3.        , 45.4,  9.1] ]
result = dict()
for group, *values in first_list:
    if group not in result:
        result[group] = [values]
    else:
        result[group].append(values)
print(result)
### if you want it back as a list:
result_list = [v for k,v in result.items()]
print(result_list)
```

Output:

```
#dict:
{1.0: [[45.4, 9.1]], 2.0: [[45.5, 9.1], [45.4, 9.2], [45.4, 9.2]], 3.0: [[45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.1]]}
#list:
[[[45.4, 9.1]], [[45.5, 9.1], [45.4, 9.2], [45.4, 9.2]], [[45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.1], [45.4, 9.1]]]
```